# Are there movements that are always unsafe?

Tags: injury-prevention

Do I eliminate certain movement from my routine, no matter what? Right now, I raise a weight overhead, crunch with a weight, and do ballistic movements. I do not feel they harm me. Are these a recipe for injuries, even with proper form?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  As written, your question is asking for opinions.

Comment: @rrirower: you are right that the question could lead to that, but it could also be answered with references.

Comment: Standing on a swiss ball juggling dumbbells. Standing on a swiss ball doing squats. Actually, pretty much anything done standing on a swiss ball seems unsafe to me, unless you're training for a Cirques du Soleil show.

Comment: @DarkHippo: apparently they indeed are many exercises standing on a swiss ball. Just Google images of it, and be amazed.

Comment: Nothing is perfectly safe. There is no way to prevent injuries with certainty, we can only reduce risk. How much risk you take and how you manage it depends a lot on your goals and your individual fitness and training. You haven't provided any of this information, so your question can not be answered, you'll only get opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some movements are unsafe. Not every person will get injured but there are exercises and activities that have higher injury rates. Specifically, the crunches you mentioned place a tremendous load on the spine. [Here is an article and video](https://uwaterloo.ca/applied-health-sciences/hes-got-our-backs) on why not to do crunches and what to do instead. Stuart McGill has a lot more info if you decide to dig deeper than the article and video.

Answer (score 0):

With proper form? Yes, they may lead to injuries, if you are attempting to lift more than what your body is capable of, or doing explosive movements without proper stretching and warmup. Everyone is different and the way our bodies respond to different exercises differ from person to person.

To prevent injuries, we need to keep in mind how much we are loading ourselves. Loading should be done progressively, and with proper care. If I want to overload 100lbs more in a week as a beginner, then I'm just asking for injuries, no matter how good my form is. Also, regarding explosive moments, yes, injuries may happen if not done under correct supervision. The problem with explosive movements is, sometimes it throws the form out of the window. We just get carried away and call injuries in. Does that mean we should give everything up? No, the idea is to make our bodies able enough to handle those. With nutrition, rest, and taking it easy, and doing things  progressively. When our muscles and tendons are strong enough, they can withstand the explosiveness, but don't forget to warm then up with light movements and do enough stretching to make them prepared for what coming next.